# pygame multiple key shooting cooldown

Tags: python, pygame

In my game the player can shoot different coloured bullets using the WASD keys. The player can shoot bullets as fast as they can press the keys right now, which means you can mash the WASD keys and shoot a stream of bullets. I've tried creating a USEREVENT to make a cooldown for when the player can shoot, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing this right because the player doesn't shoot at all when I run the game.

```
#cooldown userevent
shot_cool = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, 10)

running = True 
while running:
  clock.tick(FPS) 
    
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False #breaks out of the while loop
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.type == shot_cool: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_w: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, 10)
                player.shoot('red')   
          
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, 10)
                player.shoot('green')

            elif event.key == pygame.K_s: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, 10)
                player.shoot('white')

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, 10)
                player.shoot('blue')
```

Is there any way I can make it so the player has a short cooldown until he can fire another bullet?

Comment: you need to handle the `shot_cool` `event.type` separately, because you will never have `event.type` equal to the two different values as you are checking for at the same time.  Create a separate `shot_delay = True` every time you set the timer, and have a separate `if event.type==shot_cool`  in your event loop to set `shot_delay = False`.  Then check the `shot_delay` boolean on every shooting key to check if shooting is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you fixed your problem perfectly.  But since I already had it in my editor I decided I'd share a little more.  Since all the keys function the same way, you can handle them in the same function block, using a dictionary.  It could end up looking like this:

```
#cooldown userevent
EVT_SHOT_COOLDOWN = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

# shot cool down time
COOLDOWN_TIME_MS = 100

SHOT_KEYS = {
    pygame.K_w:'red',
    pygame.K_a:'green',
    pygame.K_s:'white',
    pygame.K_d:'blue',
}

running = True 
shot_delay = False
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False #breaks out of the while loop

        elif event_type == shot_cool:
            shot_delay = False
        
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            
            # handle shooting keys
            if (event.key in SHOT_KEYS and not shot_delay):
                pygame.time.set_timer(shot_cool, COOLDOWN_TIME_MS)
                shot_delay = True
                player.shoot(SHOT_KEYS[event.key])
            
            # handle other keys (if any)
```

Comment: I'm looking at the code now and I can't seem to get my head round why ```shot_delay``` should be ```True``` after setting the timer. I removed it to see what would happen and sure enough the problem happened again, but it worked perfectly once I put it back in. Can you explain why ```shot_delay``` should be ```True``` after setting the timer and how this actually causes a cooldown?

Comment: oh ok wait, nevermind I understand now. To start with there's no cooldown (```shot_delay = False```). Since the if statement checks for when ```shot_delay``` is false (when there isn't a cooldown), if shot_delay remained false, this would constantly pass the conditions for the if statement. When shot_delay is set to true a cooldown occurs, the player can't shoot until the USEREVENT occurs again in the program because the conditions for the if statement have not been met. When the USEREVENT occurs again, the cooldown is set to false. I probably worded this in the worst way possible

Comment: one thing I'm wondering though. Since this cooldown event occurs in the background constantly anyway and doesn't need to be stopped at all, why should I set the timer again after each key? I tried removing the timer setting commands (inside the if statements for key presses) and the problem started to happen again but I'm not sure as to why

Comment: the `and not shot_delay` in the event handler prevents the timer from being triggered more than once.  You noticed that if you set the `shot_delay` True without starting the timer, it will never get set back to False by the timer event.  If shot_delay never is False, no shooting keys will function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from RufusVS, what you said has worked perfectly. This is the working code:

```
shoot_cooldown = pygame.USEREVENT +2
pygame.time.set_timer(shoot_cooldown, 100)
shot_delay = False

running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False 
        if event.type == shoot_cooldown:
            shot_delay = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_w and shot_delay == False: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shoot_cooldown, 100)
                shot_delay = True
                player.shoot('red')             
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a and shot_delay == False: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shoot_cooldown, 100)
                shot_delay = True
                player.shoot('green')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s and shot_delay == False: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shoot_cooldown, 100)
                shot_delay = True
                player.shoot('white')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d and shot_delay == False: 
                pygame.time.set_timer(shoot_cooldown, 100)
                shot_delay = True
                player.shoot('blue')
```

Comment: Good work!  I had actually edited your source to show you what was needed and it is almost identical to what you have here!  Glad to have helped!